# SQLite get item by row/column

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

```
def get_siege(id):
    c.execute("SELECT siege FROM gods where name = 'Agni' ")
    # c.execute("SELECT name, siege FROM gods where name = %s " % (id))
    return c.fetchall()
```

The table is called gods and the two columns are name (text) and siege (int). the second line is an test example where I retrieve the gods' siege stat by name. Specifically Agni is the name of the god and that works fine. Im making a method that allows me to pass the name through the method to retrieve the siege stat. the third line is what I thought should work but returns no such column: Agni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that used different syntax.

```
    c.execute("SELECT name, siege FROM gods where name = :god",  {"god" : id})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not do string formatting, use the below code that should be fine and more secure and convert the param to a tuple

```
c.execute("SELECT name, siege FROM gods where name = %s ", % (id,))
```

Comment: thats almost literally what i had in the third line and did not work.